# How to fill the space between two arcs and two segments in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization

I know this kind of questions has been posted several times, but hear me out first before you decide anything.

In short, I want to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

All the curves are a sixth of a circle, the three poly-lines approximate three arms of a spiral, I need to fill all regions defined by two arms and two arcs.

I had viewed a bunch of questions on this site dealing similar problems, all of them mentioned `ax.fill_between` method, but it involves NumPy arrays, and I did not use NumPy arrays to do the calculations.

The function that calculates the things is the following (minus the bounding box part):

```py
def polygon_spiral(unit, iterations, num_colors=12):
    step = 1530/num_colors
    palette = ['#'+spectrum_position(round(step*i), 1) for i in range(num_colors)]
    colors = [palette[0]]
    radius = unit*cos(30)/1.5
    y1 = -radius/2
    x1 = -unit/2
    x2 = unit/2
    points = [(0, radius), (x2, y1), (x1, y1)]
    polygons = [points]
    lines = [[(0, 0), (x1/2, radius/4)], [(0, 0), (0, y1)], [(0, 0), (x2/2, radius/4)]]
    side = 4
    left_start, left_end = points[0], points[2]
    down_start, down_end = points[2], points[1]
    right_start, right_end = points[1], points[0]
    for i in range(iterations):
        left = make_polygon(left_start, left_end, side)
        down = make_polygon(down_start, down_end, side)
        right = make_polygon(right_start, right_end, side)
        polygons.append(left)
        polygons.append(down)
        polygons.append(right)
        colors.extend([palette[(i+1)%num_colors]]*3)
        half = (side/2).__ceil__()
        left_start, left_end = left[half-1:half+1]
        lines[0].append(mid(left_start, left_end))
        down_start, down_end = down[half-1:half+1]
        lines[1].append(mid(down_start, down_end))
        right_start, right_end = right[half-1:half+1]
        lines[2].append(mid(right_start, right_end))
        side += 1

    indices = {0: (1, 2), 1: (0, 2), 2: (0, 1)}
    arcs = []
    for i in range(iterations+1, 0, -1):
        points = [lines[j][i] for j in range(3)]
        (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = points
        dx = x1 - x0
        dy = y1 - y0
        r = (dx*dx + dy*dy)**.5
        
        for k, v in indices.items():
            a, b = points[k]
            thetas = []
            for h in v:
                c, d = points[h]
                angle = atan2(c - a, d - b)
                if angle < 0:
                    angle += 360
                thetas.append(angle)
            theta1, theta2 = thetas
            if theta1 > theta2:
                theta1, theta2 = theta2, theta1
            if not np.isclose(theta2 - theta1, 60):
                theta1, theta2 = theta2 - 360, theta1
            arcs.append([(a, b), r, theta1, theta2])
    
    return {'polygons': polygons, 'lines': lines, 'arcs': arcs, 'colors': colors}
```

You can see the full script on [GitHub](https://github.com/Estrangeling/Eleyi/blob/main/polygon_spiral.py).

The point is the lines are stored as three `list`s of coordinates (stored as `(x, y)` `tuple`s) of discrete vertices, and they are drawn via `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection`, and the arcs are described by the coordinate of its center, its radius, theta1 and theta2, and drawn via `matplotlib.patches.Arc`.

I did not use arrays anywhere in this script, how can I fill the areas defined by two arcs and two arms without using arrays and `fill_between`, and if that's not possible, how do I do the same calculations in a vectorized way and use `fill_between` to fill the areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it again.

[image]

Basically, I filled the regions using polygons.

Each of the regions are enclosed by four lines, two straight lines and two arcs. Both arcs span 60°.

In the `arcs` `list`, the indices of the outer and inner arcs that enclose the area have a difference of 3.

So I took each pairs of arcs with index difference of 3, and made a polygon from them.

How did I make the polygons?

The arcs span 60°, I sampled 61 points on the first arc, each pair of adjacent points have an angular difference of 1°, and sampled 61 points on the second arc in the other direction:

```py
L = len(arcs)
for i in range(3):
    level = 0
    for first, second in zip(arcs[i:L:3], arcs[i+3:L:3]):
        f = 1 - level / iterations
        r, g, b = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hues[i], f, f)
        strip_colors.append('#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(round(r*255), round(g*255), round(b*255)))
        vertices = []
        (a, b), r, theta1, theta2 = first
        for n in range(61):
            angle = theta1+n
            vertices.append((a+r*cos(angle), b+r*sin(angle)))
        (a, b), r, theta1, theta2 = second
        for n in range(61):
            angle = theta2-n
            vertices.append((a+r*cos(angle), b+r*sin(angle)))
        strips.append(vertices)
        level += 1
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/Estrangeling/Eleyi/blob/main/polygon_spiral.py).